# Read local HTML file into R

Tags: html, r

I have a file on my desktop that's an HTML file. (In chrome, I right-clicked on the web page, chose "save-as" and then "Webpage, HTML"). How can I read this local file into R? Once in R I'm going to need to write some regular expressions to parse the strings and extract certain values.

Comment: Check out this post about [parsing with RegEx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)!

Answer (score 29):

use `readLines` as follows

```
 rawHTML <- paste(readLines("path/to/file.html"), collapse="\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is [`htmltools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmltools/index.html)'s `includehtml()`:

```
rawHTML <- includeHTML('path/to/file.html')

class(rawHTML)
[1] "html"      "character"
```

Answer (score 1):

Today, a better (and faster) approach is to use `xml2::read_html` which is included in the tidyverse, and can read html content from either a local file or URL.

```
library(xml2)
rawHTML <- read_html(x = "path/to/file.html")
```

Because this function can read html content from either a local file or URL, it offers input flexibility for automation built on the `rvest` library for html extraction.