# R: Modifying an R Markdown Tutorial

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following 8 plots have been made beforehand and saved as HTML files in my working directory:

```
library(plotly)

Red_A <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~var1, y = ~var2, marker = list(color = "red")) %>% 
  layout(title = 'Red A')

Red_B <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~var1, y = ~var2, marker = list(color = "red")) %>% 
  layout(title = 'Red B')

Blue_A <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~var1, y = ~var2, marker = list(color = "blue")) %>% 
  layout(title = 'Blue A')

Blue_B <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(100,100,100), var2 = rnorm(100,100,100)) %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~var1, y = ~var2, marker = list(color = "red")) %>% 
  layout(title = 'Blue B')

htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(Red_A), "Red_A.html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(Red_B), "Red_B.html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(Blue_A), "Blue_A.html")
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(Blue_B), "Blue_B.html")
```

**My Question:** Using this template over here (https://testing-apps.shinyapps.io/flexdashboard-shiny-biclust/) - I would like to make a flexdashboard that allows the user to select (from two dropdown menus) a "color" and a "letter" - and then render one of the corresponding graphs (e.g. col = Red & letter = B -> "Red B").  I would then like to be able to save the final product itself as an HTML file. This would look something like this:

[image]

I tried to write the Rmarkdown Code for this problem by adapting the tutorial:

```
---
title: "Plotly Graph Selector"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---
  
  
Inputs {.sidebar}
```

---

```
 selectInput("Letter", label = h3("Letter"), 
    choices = list("A" = 1, "B" = 2), 
    selected = 1)

 selectInput("Color", label = h3("Color"), 
    choices = list("Red" = 1, "Blue" = 2), 
    selected = 1)
```

How can I continue with this?

### Note

I know that it is possible to load HTML files into a dashboard that have been made beforehand, e.g.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73467711/directly-loading-html-files-in-r
<object class="one" type="text/html" data="Red_A.html"></object>
<object class="one" type="text/html" data="Red_B.html"></object>
<object class="one" type="text/html" data="Blue_A.html"></object>
<object class="one" type="text/html" data="Blue_B.html"></object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `iframe` with `renderUI` to render the HTML files locally using `addResourcePath` with the location of your files. With `paste0` and `paste` your could dynamically create the html files to select them. Here is some reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Plotly Graph Selector"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
  vertical_layout: fill
  self_contained: false
runtime: shiny
---
  
```{r global, include=FALSE}
```

Inputs {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
 selectInput("Letter", label = h3("Letter"), 
    choices = c("A", "B"), 
    selected = "A")

 selectInput("Color", label = h3("Color"), 
    choices = c("Red", "Blue"), 
    selected = "Red")
```

Row 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
addResourcePath("Downloads", "~/Downloads")
renderUI({
  color <- input$Color
  letter <- input$Letter
  tags$iframe(
    seamless="seamless",
    src=paste0("Downloads/", paste0(paste(color, letter, sep = "_"), ".html")),
    width = 600,
    height = 400)
})
```
````

Output:

[image]

---

If you want to remove the border around the plot, you could add `frameBorder = "0"` in your `iframe` call like this:

````
```{r}
addResourcePath("Downloads", "~/Downloads")
renderUI({
  color <- input$Color
  letter <- input$Letter
  tags$iframe(
    seamless="seamless",
    src=paste0("Downloads/", paste0(paste(color, letter, sep = "_"), ".html")),
    width = 600,
    height = 400,
    frameBorder = "0")
})
```
````

Output:

[image]

---

Using `getwd()` with `basename` like this:

````
```{r}
addResourcePath(basename(getwd()), getwd())
renderUI({
  color <- input$Color
  letter <- input$Letter
  tags$iframe(
    seamless="seamless",
    src=paste0(basename(getwd()), "/", paste0(paste(color, letter, sep = "_"), ".html")),
    width = 600,
    height = 400,
    frameBorder = "0")
})
```
````

Comment: @ Quinten: thank you so much for your answer!  Is it possible to use the getwd()  function to make sure the code is directly reading from the working directory?

Comment: Hi @stats_noob, Do you mean by replacing "~/Downloads" with `getwd` in `addResourcepath`?

Comment: @ Quinten: As an example, suppose my plots are currently saved here : "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents"

Comment: e.g. here is the output of" getwd()" : "C:/Users/me/OneDrive/Documents"

Comment: Please check latest edit with `getwd` and `basename`!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The code runs - but I am getting the following empty output: https://imgur.com/a/j0sB2Ri

Comment: I think I fixed it! I  changed: addResourcePath("Documents", getwd())

Comment: Aah I see, forgot to change the first argument of `addResourcePath`. Please check again edit.